# Why won't my Rails server run on OS X Lion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to run the Rails Server through my command line. I type in "rails server" in my command line, and receive this error:

```
    Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (= 1.2.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

After receiving this error, I run 'bundle install'. Once I run 'bundle install', I type in "rails server" in my command line and receive the same error:

```
    Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (= 1.2.5, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Here's a copy of my GemFile:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
    # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

    gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'

    # Use unicorn as the web server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Deploy with Capistrano
    # gem 'capistrano'

    # To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
    # gem 'ruby-debug'
    # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

    # Bundle the extra gems:
    # gem 'bj'
    # gem 'nokogiri'
    # gem 'sqlite3'
    # gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

    # Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
    # put test-only gems in this group so their generators
    # and rake tasks are available in development mode:
    # group :development, :test do
    #   gem 'webrat'
    # end
```

Can someone help me get my rails server up and running? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a server question, to those of you voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the "1.2.5" in your gemfile so the line looks like:

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

again

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried running what you suggested and it still didn't work. I guess I'll try using a web development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I once got this error a long time ago - it had something to do with having sqlite.dll in my bin or lib folder in my computer's ruby dir or something like that.  I think Michael Hartl's tutorial mentions something about it.

Comment: I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial, and can't seem to fix it. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: yeah sorry I can't be of more help -- if I do come across that error and find a solution I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to confirm that your gem is properly installed in your environment:

```
gem list
```

You can also get more information about a specific gem:

```
gem specification sqlite3-ruby
```

I am assuming that you have no issues with installing other gems - that is, you don't need to set up a http_proxy environment variable for *bundle install*.